# Using touch and sed within a find -ok command

Tags: bash, find, exec

I have some wav files. For each of those files I would like to create a new text file with the same name (obviously with the *wav* extension being replaced with *txt*).

I first tried this:

```
find . -name *.wav -exec 'touch $(echo '{}" | sed -r 's/[^.]+\$/txt/')" \;
```

which outputted

> < touch $(echo {} | sed -r 's/[^.]+$/txt/') ... ./The_stranglers-Golden_brown.wav > ?

Then *find* complained after I hit *y* key with:

> find: ‘touch $(echo ./music.wav | sed -r 's/[^.]+$/txt/')’: No such file or directory

I figured out I was using a pipe and actually needed a shell. I then ran:

```
find . -name *.wav -exec sh -c 'touch $(echo "'{}"\" | sed -r 's/[^.]+\$/txt/')" \;
```

Which did the job.

Actually, I do not really get what is being done internally, but I guess a shell is spawned on every file right ? I fear this is memory costly.
Then, what if I need to run this command on a large bunch of files and directories !?

Now is there a way to do this in a more efficient way ?
Basically I need to transform the current file's name and to feed touch command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `find` with `bash` *parameter-expansion* will do the trick for you. You don't need `sed` at all.

```
find . -type f -name "*.wav" -exec sh -c 'x=$1; file="${x##*/}"; woe="${file%.*}"; touch "${woe}.txt"; ' sh {} \;
```

The idea is the part

- `x=$1` represents each of the entry returned from the output of `find`
- `file="${x##*/}"` strips the path of the file leaving only the last file name part (only `filename.ext`)
- The part `woe="${file%.*}"` stores the name without extension, and the new file is created with an extension `.txt` from the name found.

#### EDIT

*Parameter expansion* sets us free from using *Command substitution* `$()` sub-process and *sed*.
After looking at *sh* man page, I figured out that the command up above could be simplified.

> Synopsis **-c** [-aCefnuvxIimqVEbp] [+aCefnuvxIimqVEbp] [-o option_name] [+o option_name] *command_string* [*command_name* [*argument* ...]]
> ...
> **-c** Read commands from the *command_string* operand instead of from the stan‐dard input. **Special parameter 0 will be set from the *command_name* oper‐and and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining *argument* operands**.

We can directly pass the file path, skipping the shell's name (which is useless inside the script anyway). So `{}` is passed as the *command_name* `$0` which can be expanded right away.
We end up with a cleaner command.

```
find . -name *.wav -exec sh -c 'touch "${0%.*}".txt ;' {} \;
```

Comment: That's a nice improvement, I did not think of parameter extension. Any idea of something even more lighter though ?

Comment: @Stphane: This is more reliable then messing with `sed`, having more control of what we are doing with each input and how the manipulation happens. I personally prefer this way though!

Comment: You deserve at least +1,  I'll let the question alive one or two more days so other answers can be published. If no one else submits a better answer in the meantime​ I will choose yours `:)`